# Configure Wifi from ADB

Tags: android, permissions, adb

I want to configure my Wifi AP with Adb.

I've made a Java activity which do it :

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
    wc.SSID = "\"ap_name\"";
    wc.preSharedKey  = "\"password\"";
    wc.hiddenSSID = false;
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;        

    int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res );
    boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);        
    Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );
    if (b) tv.setText("Internet conectado");
    wifi.saveConfiguration();
```

In My Manifest I have :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

When I run it from Eclipse, or from the installed app, it runs ok
But when I run it from Adb, with :

```
adb shell am start -n com.mexico.sgp/.ConfigureWifi
```

I get a permission error :

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.mexico.sgp/.ConfigureWifi }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000    cmp=com.mexico.sgp/.ConfigureWifi } from null (pid=3279, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10130
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1857)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:463)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:108)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:81)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:237)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I do to get the permissiion from adb???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your manifest, mark your service as `exported="true"`

```
<service android:name=".ConfigureWifi"
         android:exported="true" />
```

According to [official doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#exported), `exported` controls:

> Whether or not components of other applications can invoke the service or interact with it — "true" if they can, and "false" if not. When the value is "false", only components of the same application or applications with the same user ID can start the service or bind to it.

So set it to true allows adb to invoke your service.